# Generate a truth table based on 3 bit gray code

Tags: logic

I am struggling to understand gray code and how it affects output. Basically, the end goal of what I am trying to do is is to design a circuit based off of a truth table. I understand most of this, except for the gray code part.

Let's say I am given this truth table, where the output changes at each rising clock edge according to the 3 bit gray code (last value cycles back to first value). How do I fill in the output? Am I supposed to take the left value, and figure out its next value in gray code and fill that in?

```
Inputs   |  Outputs
-------------------
S2 S1 S0 | N2 N1 N0
--------------------
0  0  0  | ?  ?  ?
0  0  1  |
0  1  0  |
0  1  1  |
1  0  0  |
1  0  1  |
1  1  0  |
1  1  1  |
```

My first reaction is I see the left columns are not in grey code. Would I just fill it according to the basic grey code sequence? The 3 bit sequence for gray code is 000, 001, 011, 010, 110, 111, 101, 100. Would I just fill in the right side of the chart like 001, 011, 110, 010 etc?

Comment: I think in your second to last input row you mean 1 1 1, and I think you meant to stop after that, not put a 9th entry.

Comment: see the 2nd table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code for what I think is your desired result. I could paste that in as an answer, but that seems to be taking credit for someone else's work.

Comment: @JeremyKahan you are correct, I've amended it

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it. For people in the future who stumble upon this thread in the future, here is how to convert binary to gray code.

First, bring down most significant bit. This is the first bit of the gray code.
If we had a binary value of 100, the first bit would be 1 so the gray code is 1--.

To find the second bit of gray code, add the first bit of binary to the second bit. In 100, this would be 1+0 = 1. This is the second bit of gray code, 11-.

Next, add the second bit of binary to the third bit. This is the last bit of gray code. 100, so 0+0 = 0, and our gray code becomes 110.

For four bit conversions, simply continue the pattern but add binary bits 3 and 4 to get bit 4 of the gray code number.

The finished table for my answer is

```
Inputs   |  Outputs
-------------------
S2 S1 S0 | N2 N1 N0
--------------------
0  0  0  | 0  0  0
0  0  1  | 0  0  1
0  1  0  | 0  1  1
0  1  1  | 0  1  0
1  0  0  | 1  1  0
1  0  1  | 1  1  1
1  1  0  | 1  0  1
1  1  1  | 1  0  0
```

Comment: For further future reader, by adding the bits, the OP means to do that using XOR Operation. Like if we have a Binary Number, we can convert it into a Gray Code by, `gray = num ^ (num >> 1)`, where ^ is XOR operation.